# php Combining arrays within a multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array from $_POST:

```
array { 
["item"]=> array() { 
    [0]=> "pen" 
    [1]=> "pencil" 
    [2]=> "ruler" 

array { 
["note"]=> array() { 
    [0]=> "permanent" 
    [1]=> "not so permanent" 
    [2]=> "measures stuff" 

array { 
["cost"]=> array() { 
    [0]=> "67.99" 
    [1]=> ".15" 
    [2]=> "1.49"
```

That I want to combine into single line items, e.g

```
array { 
["line_items"]=> array() {

["0"]=> array() {
        [item]=> "pen" 
        [note]=> "permanent"
        [cost]=> "67.99"

["1"]=> array() {
        [item]=> "pencil" 
        [note]=> "not so permanent"
        [cost]=> ".15"      

["3"]=> array() {
        [item]=> "ruler" 
        [note]=> "measures stuff"
        [cost]=> "1.49"
```

I've had a look at array_merge, array_merge_recursive, array_combine, but all these functions don't do what i'm looking for. I've tried a few different for each and for loops, but I just can't get my head around it.

Please ask if you need more info, this isn't very clear, but like i say, my head - struggling to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to come up with something on your own for this:

```
$length = count($_POST['item']);
$items = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $item = array();
    $item['item'] = $_POST['item'][$i];
    $item['note'] = $_POST['note'][$i];
    $item['cost'] = $_POST['cost'][$i];
    $items[] = $item;
}

var_dump($items);
```

Should get you what you need. Note that it has no error checking or validation of any kind - you'll want to add that.

**Edit**: made a stupid mistake in my answer - corrected.

Comment: You are a golden god, thank you so much. Such a quick answer too. got it working perfectly. One day i'll be as good as you. Next time i'm in the pub i'll buy a random person a pint, hopefully it will be you.

Comment: @Mason8r Haha - appreciate the compliments. Glad it worked out for you  and welcome to Stack overflow!